# Future is stuck on return statement and never completes the function future called from

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

getInitialTripData calls getCurrentLocationData with await but it never prints "coming here 1" and on getCurrentLocationData the function goes on till printing the data and then stuck on return statement i dont know what the issue is

```
setInitialTripData() async {
    print("coming here");
    MapLocation startingPoint=await Get.find<LocationService>().getCurrentLocationData();
    print("coming here 1");
      if (startingPoint != null) {
        tripData.startingPoint = startingPoint;
        startingPointTextController.text = startingPoint.name;
        update();
      }
  }

Future<MapLocation> getCurrentLocationData()async{
   try{
     if(!locationAllowed.value){
       return null;
     }
     LocationData position=await _location.getLocation();
     List<geo.Placemark> placemark =
     await geo.placemarkFromCoordinates(position.latitude, position.longitude);
     if(placemark.length==0 || placemark==null){
       return null;
     }
     MapLocation mapLocation=MapLocation(name: "${placemark[0].name.isNotEmpty? placemark[0].name+", ":""}${placemark[0].subAdministrativeArea.isNotEmpty? placemark[0].subAdministrativeArea+", ":""}${placemark[0].isoCountryCode.isNotEmpty? placemark[0].isoCountryCode:""}",latitude: position.latitude,longitude: position.longitude);
    print(mapLocation.getDataMap());
     return mapLocation;
   }
   catch(e){
     return null;
   }
  }
```

Comment: Turn null safety on. A little pain will give a lot of gain. Also are you using the lints package?

Answer (score 0):

`getCurrentLocation` has a bunch of chances to return `null`, and you're not handling a potential `null` return value in `setInitialTripData`

your code only continues executing if `startingPoint != null` it seems.

Comment: its not even printing this statement  print("coming here 1"); so it doesn't matter if its null or not.Future is stuck after it prints this line print(mapLocation.getDataMap()); and just stuck there doesn't return data

Answer (score 0):

Well Problem is in your `getCurrentLocationData` function because your function is expecting a return value of type **MapLocation** because you have declared in your function it's return type here

```
Future<MapLocation> getCurrentLocationData(){}
```

That's why when you `return null` from this function this throws an error and `break` your functions.

What you need to do is either remove return `type` or make it `nullable` whichever works fine like :

```
Future<MapLocation?> getCurrentLocationData(){}
```

Or

```
Future getCurrentLocationData(){}
```

Apart from that you need to make the `receiving` variable `nullable` so that it can handle `null` data

```
MapLocation? startingPoint=await Get.find<LocationService>().getCurrentLocationData();
```

Comment: i am not using null safety and even if i remove type it wont return it will just print the data print(mapLocation.getDataMap()); and it will just stop there

Comment: try returning Future.value() instead of null once.